# Ocean SDK get property value at cell

Tags: properties, ocean

In my plugin I get property as an input parameter. I'm trying to get property value at particular cell. I've checked that value at the cell is really defined, but I get Nan. 
Code sample:

```
 double permValueCell;
 Index3 TestIndex = new Index3(54,8,7);
 permValueCell = _propPermeability[TestIndex];
```

Firstly I thought that there is some problem in getting property as parameter, but during debug I saw that description section of the property displays a correct name. What can be wrong ?

Comment: Is Index3(54,8,7) the cell you are looking at in a Petrel window ?  If so this is the display index and may not be the same cell in Ocean.

Comment: But how is it possible to establish the relationship between indexes used inside ocean and those displayed in petrel 3d window ? Is it just connected to this grid "Cell origin settings" ? But looks like there is not just like that... And how is it possible to handle that issue in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

In Petrel, the cell index seen in the UI is not the same as stored in Ocean.

You can convert between the two by using the ModelingUnitSystem class in Petrel 2014.

Look at :

```
Slb.Ocean.Petrel.ModelingUnitSystem.ConvertIndexFromUI
Slb.Ocean.Petrel.ModelingUnitSystem.ConvertIndexToUI
```